# Auth::login isn't working in Laravel 9. Redirecting user back to /login after registering

Tags: laravel, authentication, breeze

I am using the standard Laravel Authentication.

Here is my RegisteredUserController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Laravel\Cashier\Exceptions\IncompletePayment;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $userID = uniqid('u-');

        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);
        
        $user = User::create([
            'unique_id' => $userID,
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'name' => $request->first_name." ".$request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'user_role' => 'approval_pending',
            'show_in_directory' => 'on',
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

Whenever a new user registers, I can see that it creates an entry in the database with all of the information they put in accounted for. So, I know that the event(new Registered($user)); is working.

However, the line after that: Auth::login($user); does not seem to be working, because when it redirects, the dashboard (where they are redirected to by default) sees that they are not logged in, and kicks them back to the login screen.

However... if I attempt to log in after that, it logs them in just fine.

I initially thought that it might be a problem with the RouteServiceProvider::HOME specification on the redirect. I attempted to change it to some other routes – and I can see in my console that it does indeed send them to the page – but, because they are not logged in, it immediately kicks them back to the log in screen.

So – I know the redirect is working as it should. The question really is – why is the Auth::login($user) not working?

I attempted to set the contents of that function to a variable:

`$auth = Auth::login($user);`

and then ran:
`dd($user)` first to make sure that the $user object wasn't empty (it wasn't).

Then I ran:
`dd($auth);`

which returns null.

So – I am sure that is why the redirect isn't working. I'm just not sure why.

Any ideas?

Comment: `SessionGuard@login` returns `void`, so `null` is not a sign of anything ... also what field is your primary key?

Comment: primary key is set to the default "id" field.

Comment: Have you tried `Auth::login($user, true);`? the extra parameter indicates the user should be remembered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Gave it a try – but unfortunately, no dice.

Comment: Is CSRF working on the register page or did you have to do something to bypass it.  I ask because it sounds like sessions are not working.  On apache servers this can be caused by inadvertently echoing something to the output before cookies are set.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got the same problem.

In my case, i'm using `uuid` as an `id` field, it seems like `event(new Registered($user));` can't read the `id`, so it keeps return `id`'s `0` when you authenticate, but inside your database, `id` field was not `0`.

Here my solution, add this code on top inside `User` model:

```
protected $keyType = 'string';

public $incrementing = false;
```

Hope this solution can also help you.